# get rows between specific day and month irrespective of year

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I have a small T-SQL problem I am trying to solve but I can't seem to get it working.

How can I get all rows where startDate is between the 16th of August and the 19th of September, irrespective of the year, in T-SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl
WHERE (MONTH(dt) = 8 AND DAY(dt) >= 16) OR (MONTH(dt) = 9 AND DAY(dt) <= 19)
```

Answer (score 0):

For Sql Server I'll use following query.

```
select * from (
select *,DATEFROMPARTS(2011,MONTH(CreateDate),DAY(CreateDate)) as dt from tblAction
) as x
where x.dt between
DATEFROMPARTS(2011,3,6) and
DATEFROMPARTS(2011,8,2)
```

See if it helps..:)